# Removing everyting before first comma and after third comma

Tags: regex

I have the following text in my notepad++:

```
 14, CANCELLATION,rigtt,14;
    192, CERTIFICATE,LatL,192;
    32, TARGET, LATP, 32
```

I want to remove everything before first comma and after third comma so the above will be like this:

```
CANCELLATION,rigtt
CERTIFICATE,LatL
TARGET, LATP
```

what regular expression should I use to achieve the above string. I tried `*.`, and that did not work.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming all the lines have ; at the end.

I would do it in 2 steps.

1. Use replace all (CTRL+H) 
   Replace this [0-9],?   with  nothing

2.Use replace all (CTRL+H)
Replace this   , *;   with  nothing(there is a space between , and *)

Answer (score 0):

regular expression :

```
^[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,]*).*$
```

playground for the above: https://regex101.com/r/puCyO3/2

explanation :

```
^        scan from the beginning of the string
[^,]*,   until the 1st comma
([^,]*,  capture up to and including the 2nd comma ...
[^,]*)   ... and up to but not including the 3rd comma
.*$      ignoring everything until the end of the string
```

Comment: `[^,]` matches line break chars, too, and may match across lines. `^[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,]*).*$` will also keep spaces around the value, and OP output shows that those should be removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I noticed that ambiguity, too, between the stated goal and the shown output; I went with the stated goal;  Anjali : adjust as necessary, according to whether you want what you said you want, or what you showed you want

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273413/3832970) where I am using lazy quantifiers to achieve the "trimming" effect.